# Odd SpriteKit frame rate drop - lingering SKPhysicsBody instances suspected

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, sprite-kit, frame-rate

I am working on a small SpriteKit game, and the game involves maneuvering a player SKSpriteNode through a cascading series of gates that are generated:

[Screenshot from an iPhone 5c](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fadct.jpg)

In order to stop the frame rate from dropping over time, I have implemented a simple block of code that goes in my GameScene's update function:

```
        for node in children {
        if(node.position.y < -100) {
            if(node.name == "player") {
                switchMode(2)
            }
            node.removeFromParent()
        }
```

The game starts off at a perfect 60 fps, and remains at that state for a few minutes.

Unexpectedly, a frame rate drop occurs after the game has been running for around 2-3 minutes on an iPhone 5c, and after 4 minutes or so the game drops to an unplayable 12 fps. Looking at my code, not much else happens over time in the update loop, so this behavior is quite odd. Interestingly, when the game is lost and the game over GUI is called up, the framerate recovers to 60 fps, but drops back to a slower FPS based on how long the game has been running for.

I suspect that the SKNodes for the barriers are somehow not being properly deleted, perhaps that the SKPhysicsBody instances attached to the gate SKSpriteNode instances are remaining active and straining the CPU. Is there anything I can / need to do to explicitly remove the .physicsBody property of the SKSpriteNode instances to remove them from physics calculations? I have tried setting .physicsBody = nil during removal, and that has not helped.

I am running Xcode 7.1 on OS X 10.11.1, testing my app on an iPhone 5c running iOS 9.

Comment: If you're watching the FPS, then I assume you have `skView.showsFPS` set to `YES`. Have you also enabled `.showsDrawCount` and `.showsNodeCount`?

Comment: @Thunk as is visible in the screenshot, .showsFPS and .showsNodeCount are enabled, although .showsDrawCount is not. Also, the node count shown by the SKView is only the number of nodes on the screen. I did some monitoring with children.count a few days ago and it appears the SKNodes are being successfully removed.

Comment: Forgive me, but what is `children`?  Do you remove you nodes from that array?  If that array is constantly building up, that could cause a slow down  by having to cycle through all of them 60 times a second.  Another thing for performance, is to only check through `children` every second or so (maybe faster if needed).

Comment: @Gliderman my bad, I forgot to clarify. children is the SKNode instances under GameScene, and I've managed to keep the array size low as intended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm, last time I monitored the GameScene's children.count I must have not monitored for long enough. Contrary to what I thought I confirmed, children.count slowly climbed, although it did not increase on every update. I suspected that some gates were not being generated properly and weren't falling down through the screen. I looked through my source code, and I found this mess:

```
 func genObstacle(rift: Int, x: CGFloat, width: CGFloat) {
    if(width > 0) {
        let obstacle = SKSpriteNode(color: obstacleColor(rift), size: CGSize(width: frame.width * width / 12, height: frame.width / 12))
        obstacle.position = CGPoint(x: frame.width * (x + width / 2) / 12, y: frame.height * 9 / 8)
        obstacle.position.x += (CGFloat)(rift - activeRift) * 2048
        obstacle.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: obstacle.size)
        obstacle.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVector(dx: 0, dy: (CGFloat)(-500 - rift * 300) * (frame.height / 500))
        obstacle.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
        obstacle.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
        obstacle.physicsBody?.linearDamping = 0
        obstacle.physicsBody?.mass = 32767
        obstacle.name = "obs"
        addChild(obstacle)
    }
}
```

The random generation uses random integers (casted to floats) to decide how many "units" wide a gate piece should be. I accidentally left in the possibility for the width to be 0, which created buggy SKNodes which were lingering around and complicating physics. To anyone else who has an odd frame rate drop with SpriteKit, **keep an eye on your GameScene's children.count**, often that can be an indicator of the source of your issue.